# How to combine fuzzy_like_this and filter in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I want to filter the results of a `fuzzy_like_this` query. So I basically want to combine the following snippets - the query:

```
{
  "query": {
     "flt": {
     "like_text": "acme",
     "fields": ["company.name"]
   }
}
```

and the filter:

```
{
  "filter": {
  "not": {
    "term": {"deleted": "true"}
  }
}
```

All attempt to combine these in a sensible way result in a huge blob of ES error text. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "flt": {
          "like_text": "acme",
          "fields": ["company.name"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "not": {
          "term": {"deleted": "true"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why in my query found this error:No query registered for [flt]?